# ADD CONSTRAINT "CHECK ([TYPE] IN (...) Gan I get the constraint values from other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I'm having a problem building some constraints in my MSSQL database. This database will be used for a small electronics store. For the moment I have this to create my database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT] (
[ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
[ID_SUBCAT] INT NOT NULL,
[KORTING] FLOAT NULL,
[PRIJS] FLOAT NULL,
[TYPE] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL )
```

And now I want to add a constraint that the [TYPE] column can only hold certain values. So I came up with this constraint

```
GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT] ADD CONSTRAINT [ProperTypeEntered] CHECK ([TYPE] IN ('Camera', 'Lens'))
```

But when I have a new type that I want to add I always have to edit this constraint because the values are hardcoded in the constraint. So I was hoping that I could make a second table with all the types in like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TYPES] (
[ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
[NAAM] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL )
```

And just have a constraint that will allow only that are inserted in the TYPES.NAAM column.

Is that in anyway possible or am I just overlooking something? My knowledge of SQL is limited so any help would be great! :)

Comment: NO, AFAIK, you can't use query/data from another table in check constraint. Use trigger instead.

Comment: Just sounds like you want a foreign key constraint.

Comment: I agree with Damien: you want a foreign key, not a check constraint

Comment: Woeps, yes Damien and the unknown horse may be correct :) It seems I wanted to make thinks to complicated then, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not able to make a constraint that does a query.  But you could do it based on a trigger for insert/update, that would query your second table, if the "type" isn't found you could throw an expection which would cause the insert/update to fail.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create another table, like you're suggesting, only call it ProductTypes. Add a new INT Column called TypeID to dbo.Products. Create a Foreign Key from dbo.Products.TypeID to dbo.ProductTypes.ID. Make sure you have all of the types added into your dbo.ProductTypes table. Also, add a column "IsActive" BIT so that you don't have to delete product types later. If you have any products that aren't in the types table, after you have the foreign key, insert NULL.